# Set TableView as central widget in dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I'm now develop a GUI using QT in C++. I know we can use function `setCentralWidget` to set a widget as central widget of mainwindow, but how can I do that in dialog.

Comment: Use `QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(your_dialog);` `lay->addWidget(your_tableview);`

Comment: This might be also interesting: [Qt Examples And Tutorials](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html). ;-)